# failed to open stream: No such file or directory generate:seed [--path="..."] [--templatePath="..."] tableName

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I tried running the command:

```
php artisan generate:seed Houses
```

However, I got the error:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory generate:seed [--path="..."] [--templatePath="..."] tableName
```

I migrated my table and generated my controller and table with php artisan generate. I am using Laravel 4.2. Is there something missing? I am trying to follow the instructions of a tutorial and there are certain artisan commands that don't work. Like I tried to generate the migration files and it gave me the same error, but I noticed that there were migration files already generated after I generated the controller and the table.

Comment: Do you use this [generator](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators)?

Comment: Please provide more information about what package you are using to have that generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you right now that the command you're using won't work. As well, make sure the tutorial you're following isn't for Laravel 5 as that version has much more artisan commands than 4.

It looks like you're trying to seed your database. Have you tried this command?

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

This should do what you want, assuming your migration files are coded properly. In general, I would suggest to read up just a bit more on the topic so you can better understand how it all works.

- [Laravel Migrations & Seeding (4.2)](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations)
- [Laravel Artisan CLI (4.2)](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/artisan)